# Flash Builder Clean Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

In flash builder I'm having a slight issue. Whenever I am debugging and my application runs into an error. I have to clean the project everytime to make it work. Otherwise it doesn't launch it but gets stuck in connecting to debugger. Any ideas on the fix?

Comment: What browser are you running your apps in?

Comment: Here everyone gets retarded errors (like "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Function.") once FB is started. After the first Clean it usually works. It's likely somewhat related to some library we use.

Comment: Yes, I also have this issue. Haven't been able to find a solution, other than having to clean every time I want to compile.

Comment: One solution, I've found for it (only web player) is not debugging in a browser. Don't generate html wrapper,uncheck copy non-embedded files to output (under actionscript compiler in project properties)

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall your flash player and re-install the debug player. It sometime happens when applications/software updates.

Comment: Done and it's still there. I have the same issue at my work machine and my home machine. But no one else seems to be able to replicate the issue on their machines.